# Using numpy.linalg.svd on a 12 x 12 matrix using python

Tags: python, numpy, camera, svd

I want to perform an SVD on a 12*12 matrix. The `numpy.linalg.svd` works fine. But when I try to get the 12*12 matrix A back by performing u*s*v , i dont get it back.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

import scipy as sp

from scipy import linalg, matrix

a_matrix=np.zeros((12,12))

with open('/home/koustav/Documents/ComputerVision/A2/codes/Points0.txt','r') as f:

    for (j,line) in enumerate(f):
         i=2*j
         if(i%2==0):
        values=np.array(map(np.double,line.strip('\n').split(' ')))
        a_matrix[i,4]=-values[2]
        a_matrix[i,5]=-values[3]
        a_matrix[i,6]=-values[4]
        a_matrix[i,7]=-1
        a_matrix[i,8]=values[1]*values[2]
        a_matrix[i,9]=values[1]*values[3]
        a_matrix[i,10]=values[1]*values[4]
        a_matrix[i,11]=values[1]*1

        a_matrix[i+1,0]=values[2]
        a_matrix[i+1,1]=values[3]
        a_matrix[i+1,2]=values[4]
        a_matrix[i+1,3]=1
        a_matrix[i+1,8]=-values[0]*values[2]
        a_matrix[i+1,9]=-values[0]*values[3]
        a_matrix[i+1,10]=-values[0]*values[4]
        a_matrix[i+1,11]=-values[0]*1


s_matrix=np.zeros((12,12))

u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(a_matrix,full_matrices=1)

k=0

while (k<12):

    s_matrix[k,k]=s[k]

    k+=1
print u

print '\n'

print s_matrix

print '\n'

print (u*s_matrix*v)
```

These are the points that i have used:

```
285.12 14.91 2.06655 -0.807071 -6.06083

243.92 100.51 2.23268 -0.100774 -5.63975

234.7 176.3 2.40898 0.230613 -5.10977

-126.59 -152.59 -1.72487 4.96296 -10.4564

-173.32 -164.64 -2.51852 4.95202 -10.3569

264.81 28.03 2.07303 -0.554853 -6.05747
```

Please suggest something...

Comment: when printing, you're miltiplying them elementwise in the last. Have a look at the exmples in the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except from saving some code and time by using built in functions like `numpy.diag`, your problem seems to be the `*` operator. In numpy you have to use `numpy.dot` for matrix multiplication. See the code below for a working example...

```
In [16]: import numpy as np

In [17]: A = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)

In [18]: A
Out[18]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])


In [19]: u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(A)

In [20]: S = np.diag(s)

In [21]: S = np.vstack([S, np.zeros((2,3)) ])

In [22]: #fill in zeros to get the right shape

In [23]: np.allclose(A, np.dot(u, np.dot(S,v)))
Out[23]: True
```

`numpy.allclose` checks whether two arrays are numerically close...